# How to change permissions in application without opening settings

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I have repeatedly seen how native iOS apps allow changing permissions from their UI, but when I decided to add such functionality to my Flutter app, I couldn't find anything about it. All information concerns only checking statuses, and if it is necessary to change something, it is sent to the phone settings. Is there a way to change permissions without opening system settings while staying in the app?

Comment: Have you tried permission handler too?

Comment: @KaushikChandru Yes, but it works as I describe. The permission handler only tells you what permissions your app has and can then open the settings, but it doesn't give you a tool to change the app's permissions inside the app. Сorrect me if I'm wrong.

Comment: On iOS you only get a chance to ask for a permission once in app. Once the user has responded you cannot ask again. At that point the user can change settings only in the settings app